# Complete formulas book for Communication System engineer

Tags: it.information-theory, fourier-analysis, signal-analysis

I'm looking for a formulas book.

I'm currently student in Communication Systems and we have several courses involving mainly complex analysis, fourier analysis, signal processing, information theory and sometimes other principles and I need a lot of books for all these formulas.

Does someone knows a book with these formulas inside ?

It doesn't need to have demonstration or long explanation, I just need something to replace the stack of books I have.

The *best* one I found so far is the [Gieck](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071457747), but there are more than a half of the book I'll never use. I want something more specific for signal processing and information theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest "Handbook of Formulas and Tables for Signal Processing", by Alexander D. Poularikas.

[This link](http://www.crcnetbase.com/isbn/978-0-8493-8579-7) should help you.

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849385792) is the amazon link.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I want ! Thank you very much ! Really sorry that I cannot upvote …